# form_for route error [RoR]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method called "createpost" in "topics_controller" which I am trying access from the show inside "topics_controller" but I keep getting a route error.

The Form:

```
<%= form_for @community_post, :url => { :action => "createpost", :controller=> "community_topics" } do |f| %>

<%= render 'error_messages' %>

<%= f.label :text %>
<%= f.text_area :text %>

<%= hidden_field_tag :community_topic_id, @community_topic.id %>

<br>

<%= f.submit "Submit reply" %>
```

The Controller Action:

```
  def createpost
    @community_post  = CommunityPost.new(community_post_params)

    @community_post.user_id = current_user.id   
    @community_post.community_topic_id = params[:community_topic_id]

    if @community_post.save
        redirect_to "/community_topics/#{@community_post.community_topic_id}", notice: 'Community post was successfully created.'
    else
        render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

What am I doing wrong so I can correct it? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of `routes.rb`. Do you have the route for member action `createpost` defined?

Comment: I didn't think I needed to because, Its not supposed to be publicly routed for someone just for inside my application. All I have right now is   resources :community_topics
  resources :community_posts in relation to it

Comment: Can u show the routing error atleast? U ve specified topics_controller as well as community_topics controller

Comment: It makes no difference if the action will be "publicly routed" or not. Rails cannot figure out what action to call when it encounters url `/community_posts/createpost` - it is not defined.

Comment: ActionController::UrlGenerationError in CommunityTopics#show
Showing Application/community_topics/show.html.erb where line #30 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"createpost", :id=>"11", :controller=>"community_topics"}

Answer (score 0):

You should have in your routes something like:

```
resources :comunity_topics do
  post 'createpost', action: 'createpost'
end
```

and the form route should be something like:

```
createpost_comunity_topics_path
```

Answer (score 0):

Either rename the method `createpost` in controller to `create` and remove the url option for form_for in view. Or define the route, if you really want use the `createpost` action like this:

```
resources :community_posts do
  collection do
    post :createpost
  end
end
```

But I suspect that you are following some old tutorial from the times when Rails had routes that contained the name of controller and action to be executed. This approach was abandoned in favor of RESTful routes.

Read the current docs here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default